# Create Splash Screen in Excel with a variable timer and variable text

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

I have a Userform.
On the Userform is a Label.

In the Userform_Initialize() event I use the code:

to close the Userform after x seconds have elapsed.

In a module I have the

```
sub KillForm()
Unload UserForm1
end sub
```

Now I want to open the Userform through a button-click on a worksheets, and pass the string strMessage for the label and the seconds x to the userform, so I create a sub in a module

```
Sub ShowMessage(strMessage As String, x As Integer)
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = strMessage
userform1.show
End Sub
```

and call the routine at the On_Click event of the button

```
ShowMessage "Hello World.", 3
```

Allas, it doesn't work. x is not 3 on the userform, always 0.

I tried Public x as Integer on top of the Userform module and the general module. No luck.
When I replace x with a number such as 3 in the OnTime line it works, the form appears with strMessage as label caption, and it disappears after the static time. But I would like to make the time dynamic with the variable x.

So: How can I pass the value of x to the Userform and into the routine

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, x), "KillForm"
```

Thanks
AG

Comment: Have you tried decalring the x variable as a Public? ex... "Dim x As Public"  That will keep the x value available for all subs.  Be careful as if you have anyother modules that use x they will now default to the original declared Public variable.

Comment: Is that really the correct form ("dim x as public")? I get an error message.

Comment: See this ;) http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?555880-Creating-Splash-Screen-in-MS-Office-2003

Comment: Sorry that should have been Public x As Variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that no other operation is required to run in the background during the display of the splashscreen, you could also modify `ShowMessage` the following way:

```
Sub ShowMessage(strMessage As String, intDisplayTime As Integer)
    Dim dblStartTime as Double

    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = strMessage
    UserForm1.Show

    dblStartTime = Timer
    If dblStartTime + intDisplayTime >= 86400 Then 
        dblStartTime = dblStartTime - 86400
    End If

    While Timer - dblStartTime < intDisplayTime
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Unload UserForm1    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works fine! For the record, any idea how to pass an argument to a userform_initialize event? I read that declaring the variable as public (e.g. "public x as integer") on top of a module should do it, but it didn't work for me, I probably overlooked something.

Comment: Got the original code working now as well. Declared Public variable in Module, and made sure public variable has a UNIQUE NAME... rookie mistake.

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot pass an argument to the _initialize event of any class (including userform) in VBA. If you declare it public, you can though assign a value to the variable userform1.x from outside - though only after the initialize code ran.